# Rendering partials failing in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's the partial view I'm trying to render if an user is logged in

```
<div class='row'>
```

## Post a project

```
<% form_for @project do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title, class:'form-control' %>
<%= f.text_area :brief, class: 'form-control' %>
<%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

In the main view when I try calling the partial, there's no error, but the partial doesn't render

```
<div class='col-lg-6'>
    <% if current_user %>
        <% render 'projects/new_project' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

This is my current_user method, defined in the application controller. I've also defined it as a helper method to use in a view template.

```
private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  helper_method :current_user
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to render, you need to output the `render`'s returned value using `<%=...`:

```
<%= render 'projects/new_project' %>
```

The expression(s) within the erb tags only get evaluated without the equals sign.  In order to display the result of the expression, you need to include the equals sign; place your code within `<%=...%>`

Similarly, for you `form_for` call:

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed that, now its rendering the h1 but still not the form.

Comment: Same rule for `form_for`, i.e. `<%= form_for... %>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to appreciate that `<%=` is an output tag

This means every time you want to output something in a non-native Ruby file (`.erb` etc), you'll have to use `<%=`

This is contrary to `<%` which does not output anything, but still performs the functions you specify

---

**Partial**

Also, you need to ensure your partial syntax is right:

```
#app/views/controller/you_view.html.erb
<%= render partial: "projects/new_project" %>

#app/views/projects/_new_project.html.erb
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class:'form-control' %>
    <%= f.text_area :brief, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```